# How do I override a getter for a KVO-compliant property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsoperation

I want to create a subclass of NSOperation that needs to customize `-isReady`, the getter for a KVO-compliant property.  My override would do a Boolean-AND of my custom test and `super`'s version of the method.  But the override still has to keep KVO-compliance.  So, how?

Comment: How does KVO affect a property getter?

Comment: I don't want to accidentally write the override such that it's non-KVO-compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing too special, as synthesized properties are KVC and KVO compliant:

The property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter=isReady) BOOL ready;`
```

The implementation:

```
@synthesize ready;

- (BOOL) isReady {
   // your custom logic here.
}
```

For an `NSOperation` subclass, KVO notifications for those properties will be automatic. You do not need to do anything more (you do not need to call will/didSetValueForKey).
If the behavior of the `NSOperation` set accessors such as `isReady` or `isFinished` is dependent on other properties or key paths, be sure to register them with KVO:

```
+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished {
    NSSet   *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"finished"];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Important for my code is that the implementation of `isReady` incorporates the superclass' version. There are KVO notifications when either version changes, which is perfect for me because listeners can't tell which version broadcasted. (I'll be in trouble if I had to suppress the superclass' KVO notifications.)

Comment: I've been meaning to answer and close the query myself, but I procrastinated. Good thing for you since I'll probably give you credit.